# First year undergrad probability question

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I was studying for my Probability and Statistics course and came across a problem (which is the same as this question: [Probability for phones](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2130262/probability-for-phones) but with a different sub-part).

The problem is,

> Out of fifteen phones received at a service center, there are five cellular, five corded, and five cordless. What is the probability that two phones of each type are among the first six serviced?

Since we have to have two phones of each type, we can pick the phones in $^5\text{C}_2$ ways per type. We have $15$ phones and we have to choose $6$ to service first so we can do that in $^{15}\text{C}_6$ ways. So if $E$ is the event that among the first six phones that are serviced, two are of each type, then $$P(E) = \frac{(^5\text{C}_2)^3}{^{15}\text{C}_6} \approx 0.1998$$

Is my reasoning correct? If not, then could someone point out my error?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.  It should be said, though, that the problem is poorly phrased.  It requires the reader to guess at a critical assumption, namely the independence of the probability of needed repairs.  A priori, there's no reason to imagine that each of three types of phone is equally likely to need repairs early on.  It's fine to make the assumption of independence, but it should be stated explicitly.  Also, I guess we are to read it as the first six *distinct* phones to need repair.